# How to set specific item from combobox as a selected based on selected row in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, ms-access, datagridview, combobox

I have a DataGridView in FormA, and a button to FormB.
In FormB i have combobox filled by items from DataGridView on FormA.

How to set specific item from combobox as a selected based on selected row in DataGridView?

Im selecting row in FormA, click on button to FormB and ComboBox already have picked this row as a item.

Comment: Show what did you try, give us some code where you stack...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ComboBox have a property called "SelectedItem" and "SelectedIndex" as well. DataGridView have a collection of rows and columns. You can know the index of the selected row like this:

```
var SelectedRow = DGR.SelectedRows[0];
int SelectedIndex=SelectedRow.Index;
```

DGR stands for DataGridView.
You can use the selectedIndex the set the SelectedIndex of your comboBox in form B.